# How do bash variable types work and how to work around automatic interpretation?

Tags: bash, types, type-conversion

I am trying to set up a variable that contains a string representation of a value with leading zeroes. I know I can printf to terminal the value, and I can pass the string output of printf to a variable. It seems however that assigning the value string to a new variable reinterprets the value and if I then print it, the value has lost its leading zeroes.

How do we work with variables in bash scripts to avoid implicit type inferences and ultimately how do I get to the solution I'm looking for. FYI I'm looking to concatenate a large fixed length string numeric, something like a part number, and build it from smaller prepared strings.

**Update:**

Turns out exactly how variables are assigned changes their interpretation in some way, see below:

**Example:**

```
#!/bin/bash
a=3
b=4
aStr=$(printf %03d $a)
bStr=$(printf %03d $b)

echo $aStr$bStr
```

output

```
$ ./test.sh
003004
$
```

Alternate form:

```
#!/bin/bash
((a = 3))
((b = 4))
((aStr = $(printf %03d $a)))
((bStr = $(printf %03d $b)))

echo $aStr$bStr
```

output

```
$ ./test.sh
34
$
```

Comment: Could you show a code sample with sample input / current output / expected output ?

Comment: `bash` doesn't really have types. Everything is a string. Only special *operators* like `-lt` will treat their string operands in an arithmetic context. (Ignore `declare -i`, which really just forces an arithmetic context when such a variable is assigned to.)

Comment: Example added. I shy away from examples, as often respondents can get hung up on irrelevant details if there are mistakes in the example.

Comment: As it says, 'example', so no, it is not real code.

Comment: Strings and integers are types. Operations on strings make no sense to those on integers. If '006' is echoed as '6', then there is an implicit conversion before the print operation.

Comment: Posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is an important part of a good question. If the sample you post has syntax errors or is otherwise invalid bash then nobody can run your code to demonstrate your issue or point out possible problems with your implementation.

Comment: @tmj3772 I do get it. In this case, I added 4 spaces. If someone has the capacity to understand the problem enough to form an answer, I expect they would be familiar with this and be able to overlook it and/or edit the question. As it turns out, exactly how variables are assigned/referenced changes how they are presented, inclusive of these spaces.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Please post a syntactically correct example, which I can copy and paste into my bash and whcih demonstrates the problem. Also post not only which output you want to see, but post also which output you actually see on your platform.

Comment: The problem relates to how the variables are being assigned. Within the double brackets, assignments can have spaces, however seem to retain a numeric concept on the variables. Without those, it seems to be interpreted as text. Both examples shown give the actual output.

Comment: @JCollins Of course, everyone answering questions here knows `a = 3` is an invalid assignment. The problem is that we don't know if that's your real code and the reason for your problem, or if you just didn't provide a proper example because you personally don't like giving examples. It's hard to believe you actually ran that code since it would likely produce errors like `a: command not found` that you never mentioned in your question, so then we have to do more investigative work to figure out your real issue. Everyone's life is easier if you just give the proper example upfront.

Comment: @JCollins You can easily obfuscate IP by using dummy variables when needed, while keeping the script logic intact. Also, we can't guess where your exact issue is, we get a lot of "trivial" questions where the problem is caused by a basic syntax error

Comment: If by IP you mean intellectual property, it's irrelevant. We're not asking you to open-source your code, just to post a runnable sample that reproduces your problem. It doesn't even have to be copy/pasted from your codebase if you can recreate the problem with a few lines in a new script. If your real code looks like `((a = 3))` then there's no reason to post a demo of `a = 3`, all that does is force us to guess what you real code looks like to give a good answer. We don't know your level of experience in bash, so we can't just overlook the "trivial" stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `((aStr = $(printf %03d $a)))`, you are destroying again the careful formatting done by `printf`. You would see the same effect if you do a

```
(( x = 005 ))
echo $x
```

which outputs `5`.

Actually the zeroes inserted by `printf` could do harm to your number, as you see by the following example:

```
(( x = 015 ))
echo $x
```

which outputs `13`, because the `((....))` interprets the leading zero as an indication for octal numbers.

Hence, if you have a string representing a formatted (pretty-printed) number, don't use this string in numeric context anymore.

Comment: We're getting closer to an answer here. Strings get interpreted based on their format. Now in this case, is "015" stored as a string for `x`, or the number 13?

Comment: @JCollins: Everything is a string. Every variable holds a string. Numeric **interpretation** of a string occurs in numeric context of course. The evaluation in numeric context yields a new string.

Answer (score 2):

> How do bash variable types

There are no variable types. All variables are strings (type).. Variables store a value (a string), but also variables have some additional magic attributes associated with them.

There are Bash arrays, but I think it's an attribute that a variable is an array. Still, in any case, every array element holds a string. There is a "numeric" variable `declare -i var`, but it's attribute of the variable - in memory, the variable is still a string, only when setting it Bash checks if the string (still a string!) to be set is a number.

> assigning the value string to a new variable reinterprets the value

Bash does not "interpret" the value on assignment.

> How do we work with variables in bash scripts to avoid implicit type inferences

There are no "type inferences". The type of variable does not change - it holds a string.

The value of the variable undergoes different expansions and conversions depending on the *context* where it is used. For example `$(...)` removes trailing newlines. Most notably unquoted variable expansions undergo word splitting and filename expansion.

> Example:

Posting your code to shellcheck results in:

```
Line 2:
a = 3
  ^-- SC2283 (error): Remove spaces around = to assign (or use [ ] to compare, or quote '=' if literal).
 
Line 3:
b = 4
  ^-- SC2283 (error): Remove spaces around = to assign (or use [ ] to compare, or quote '=' if literal).
 
Line 4:
aStr = $(printf %03d $a)
     ^-- SC2283 (error): Remove spaces around = to assign (or use [ ] to compare, or quote '=' if literal).
       ^-- SC2046 (warning): Quote this to prevent word splitting.
                     ^-- SC2154 (warning): a is referenced but not assigned.
                     ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
aStr = $(printf %03d "$a")
 
Line 5:
bStr = $(printf %03d $b)
     ^-- SC2283 (error): Remove spaces around = to assign (or use [ ] to compare, or quote '=' if literal).
       ^-- SC2046 (warning): Quote this to prevent word splitting.
                     ^-- SC2154 (warning): b is referenced but not assigned.
                     ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
bStr = $(printf %03d "$b")
 
Line 7:
echo $aStr$bStr
     ^-- SC2154 (warning): aStr is referenced but not assigned.
     ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
          ^-- SC2154 (warning): bStr is referenced but not assigned.
          ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
echo "$aStr""$bStr"
```

Shellcheck tells you what is wrong. After fixing the problems:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=3
b=4
aStr=$(printf %03d "$a")
bStr=$(printf %03d "$b")

echo "$aStr$bStr"
```

Which upon execution outputs your expected output:

```
003004
```